# Ansible Lightspeed doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ansible

According to the Ansible Lightspeed demos and documentation, you get the code suggestion section when you place the cursor at the end of the line (written in plain language) and hit ENTER.  In example below, as it does in a couple of demo videos, when you place the cursor at the end of the commented out task, and hit ENTER, the cursor will advance to new line and an ansible code suggestion should appear.  That doesn't work, the cursor advances to the new line, as it normally would, but no suggestion section.

Snippet from playbook:

```
---

- name: 'GET INFO FROM NETWORK DEVICES'
  hosts: 'arista'
  connection: 'network_cli'
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    # -name: validate devices are reachable with ping
```

I made sure:

1. Ansible extension is installed in VS Code (v 1.80.1) and is enabled for Lightspeed:
   "ansible.lightspeed.enabled": true,
   "ansible.lightspeed.suggestions.enabled": true,
2. Connected to GitHub, the Ansible extension confirms that "Logged in as *****"
3. Confirmed that the bottom right of the VS Code window shows Ansible as the file interpreter for the playbook, that Lightspeed feature activated and proper Python environment is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the task name (remove the `#`) and add a space between the `-` and `name`

Comment: thank you, uncommenting helped.  I didn't even try it because  in the demo videos it worked on the commented out tasks.  So I thought it was actually a requirement for it to work.